# Using 'lifted index finger', as an expression for 'being lectured'

Tags: word-usage, synonyms

In a document I am using a phrase for lecturing people, but I am not sure if this expression is actually correct English, or just used in Dutch and I am literally translating it and in English it's hardly used.

I am saying: 'I have had it with the lifted index finger'.

As an expression for 'I have had it with the lecturing'.

Is that correct English?

Searching I cannot directly find many hits on it, it might be 'wagging finger', 'fingering' in English for what I have found so far. Could a native speaker help me on this? I am eventually looking for some alternative for 'I do not like being lectured', since I already used that word.

Comment: *I am saying: 'I have had it with the lifted index finger'.* This is not idiomatic.

Comment: @Greybeard I could see someone saying it in an argument with someone who habitually lifts their fingers when they're talking down to them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**I have had it with the finger wagging.**

**I have had enough of your finger wagging.**

[image]

Click on this link to see the moving image. https://media.tenor.com/images/2ce44aa0928dd53c779921ed5dac9a16/tenor.gif

**WARNING**

Be very careful how you use "fingering" it has sexual connotations if used in connection with a person.

It is okay with most inanimate objects, e.g. *What fingering do you use when you play that piano piece?*

However if you say to someone "Stop fingering me" You are accusing them of sexual assault of a particular kind.

Comment: Ah, haha, sorry did not realize about the sexual connotations, thanks for the warning.

Comment: @JaJa - No need to apologise. That's what we're here for! It is quite acceptable to ask about such meanings on this website. (as long as people ask in an adult way).

Comment: But the verb "finger" applied to a person *can* also mean to blame or implicate, similar to "point a finger at".

Comment: @nanoman - You are thinking of "to put the finger on somebody". This is completely different. *John put the finger on Mary" ---> John put the blame on Mary.* --- That's okay, but *John fingered Mary!!!!!* is definitely a sexual act.  If you doubt me, Google ***how to finger someone***

Comment: @nanoman - P.S. When I have time,  I'll add to my answer to give a fuller reply to your comment.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK nanoman is right; you can ‘finger someone for a crime’, i.e. identify them as the culprit, which is completely innocent in a sexual sense, if not a moral sense!

Comment: @gidds - I associate that with 1940s gangster movies! Maybe this is a difference between US and UK English? In any case, my warning still stands, i.e. be careful of the context if you decide to use it.

Answer (score 0):

One can just say "(so) no need for lecture (on that)"... found countless articles with that phrase.

And the raised index finger ordinary is rather a gesture of scold (scolting) than of lecture...

so one could possibly also say "don't scold me".

Answer (score 0):

There aren't really any obvious alternatives. Maybe harping on: "I've had it with them/her/him harping on". Also "going on and on" or "not letting up".

Other alternatives, depending on context, could be berating, moralising, proselytising, or harassing.

Finger-wagging, according to various dictionary definitions, is a reprimand, warning, or threat. In modern usage, it often implies moral judgement. See these examples:

https://www.politico.eu/article/germans-need-to-stop-with-the-finger-wagging/
https://www.scoop.co.nz/stories/GE2005/S00110/finger-wagging-at-senior-doctors-unhelpful.htm